# Useless use of "-" in expression "-1" in sink context (line 13)

Tags: raku

I'm trying to make tests for a function that throws an exception with this code:

```
use v6;
use Test;

plan *;

use lib "lib";
use Math::ConvergenceMethods;

sub f ($x) {return $x + 1;}


{
    is-approx: bisection(&f, -2, 0), -1;
    dies-ok: { bisection(&f, 3, 2) }, "Incorrect arguments";
}

done-testing;
```

And it returns this warnings when I run it:

```
WARNINGS for /home/antonio/Code/perl6/Math-ConvergenceMethods/t/bisection.t:
Useless use of "-" in expression "-1" in sink context (line 13)
Useless use of constant string "Incorrect arguments" in sink context (lines 14, 14)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I think you don't need the colon after `is-approx` (From the Docs https://docs.perl6.org/type/Test#sub_is-approx)

Comment: if I delete it returns an error: Two terms in a row across lines (missing semicolon or comma?)

Comment: oh colon != semicolon... What a fail haha. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `foo` in a statement of the form:

```
foo: ...
```

is a [label](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Label) where the `...` is the statement that it labels.

So the statement you've written is the same as:

```
bisection(&f, -2, 0), -1;
```

which leaves the `-1` in [sink context](https://docs.perl6.org/language/contexts#index-entry-sink_context), hence the error message.

(The message is somewhat [LTA](https://docs.perl6.org/language/glossary#index-entry-LTA) because your mistake is clearly that you thought the label syntax was a function calling syntax and while the error message does indicate the error -- `in sink context` -- the `Useless use of "-"` is additional detail that doesn't help and probably added to your confusion.)

See also [What's the difference these two function calling conventions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50222885/whats-the-difference-these-two-function-calling-conventions).

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add for those who might be confused as to when you can call a routine using the colon followed by arguments - it's an alternative format exclusively available when calling methods:

```
my @list = 1 , 2 , 3 ;
map( { $_ * 2 } , @list );  # "classic" fn call, works with or w/o brackets
@list.map: { $_ * 2 }       # OK  - calling the map method of @list, no brackets or
                            # comma (!) required.
map: { $_ * 2 } , @list ;   # fugetaboutit
```