# Perl6 Using Proxy to trigger on attribute access

Tags: raku

I am trying to implement a trigger on write access to a perl6 Class attribute. I cannot figure out the cause of the error...

... I got this notion from [How does one write custom accessor methods in Perl6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665384/how-does-one-write-custom-accessor-methods-in-perl6)

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/env perl6
  2 
  3 class MeasureSP {
  4 
  5     has Real $!value;
  6     has Str  $.units;
  7 
  8     submethod BUILD( :$!value, :$!units ) {}
  9 
 10     method value( Real $newval? ) is rw {
 11         return Proxy.new:
 12             FETCH => sub ($)           { $!value },
 13             STORE => sub ($, $newval)  { $!value = $newval },             
 14     }   
 15     
 16 }   
 17 my MeasureSP $m-sp = MeasureSP.new( value => 23, units => 'metres' );
 18 say $m-sp.units;   #metres
 19 say $m-sp.value;   #23
 20 $m-sp.value = 1;   
 21 # Cannot assign to a readonly variable or a value
 22 #in block <unit> at ./retry.p6 line 20
```

This behaviour seems to have changed - this code was working fine back in June 18 - but I want to be sure I am in step with the latest thinking.

Any help would be very much appreciated !

Comment: BTW, you may consider my `AttrX::Mooish` module – it has triggers and filters out of the box.

Comment: just needed to delete the word return - I hadn’t appreciated it is decontaminating stuff

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Either remove the `return`:

```
method value( Real $newval? ) is rw {
    Proxy.new:
        FETCH => sub ($)           { $!value },
        STORE => sub ($, $newval)  { $!value = $newval },
}
```

Or use `return-rw` if you really want to be explicit:

```
method value( Real $newval? ) is rw {
    return-rw Proxy.new:
        FETCH => sub ($)           { $!value },
        STORE => sub ($, $newval)  { $!value = $newval },
}
```

The problem is that `return` will strip away any item container, so just putting `is rw` on the `method` is not enough on its own.

As to why the posted code used to work, but no longer does: Rakudo releases in the last couple of months have included a fix for a bug that meant `Proxy` was treated differently than `Scalar` in routine return handling. The `Proxy` was not stripped in places it should have been; now it reliably is.

Comment: Ah - alles klar - thanks for the informative answer!